# How to stop RecyclerView Items from Displaying Out of Order

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView to display messages from a user and a bot, but after about 10 messages, upon scrolling, the RecyclerView's items display out of order.

I removed `setStackFromEnd()` and `setReverseLayout()` from the LinearLayoutManager my code in case that caused any issue, but that didn't solve the problem. I also added the line `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`, and although that worked, I didn't want to use that solution since it defeats the purpose of a RecyclerView.

Gets user response, adds the response to the list of messages, generates the reply, and calls calls `updateUI()`:

```
public void respond(String input) {
    int position = getMessagePosition();
    Log.d(CHAT_FRAGMENT_TAG, "Received Message: " + input);
    String reply = mBot.reply("user", input);
    Log.d(CHAT_FRAGMENT_TAG, "Bot Reply: " + reply);
    mMessages.add(new Message(reply, Message.BOT_MESSAGE, messagePosition()));
    updateUI(position);
    Log.d(CHAT_FRAGMENT_TAG, "mMessages List: " + mMessages.get(position).getText());
}
```

`updateUI()`:

```
public void updateUI(int insertPosition) {
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new MessageAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(insertPosition);
}
```

`onBindViewHolder()`:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = mMessages.get(position);

        if (getItemViewType(position) == Message.USER_MESSAGE)
            ((UserMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
        else
            ((BotMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
    }
```

`bind()`:

```
public void bind(Message message) {
        mBotTextView.setText(message.getText());
    }
```

`messagePosition()` and `getMessagePosition()`:

```
    public static int messagePosition() {
    //A convenience function to get the current position and increment it as well for the next array element.
    int returnValue = mMessagePosition;
    mMessagePosition++;
    return returnValue;
}

public static int getMessagePosition() {
    return mMessagePosition;
}
```

There is an `onClick()` method on an EditText that  takes the user's response and calls the `respond()` method. The `respond()` method gets the bot's reply, and it calls the `updateUI()` method to let the adapter know that the array is larger since new messages were added (one from the user and one from the bot). This process works fine until there are about 10 messages and the user needs to scroll. From that point, the messages reload on the screen incorrectly by repeating themselves or not loading in their correct spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same issue. Consider storing all the conversation somewhere, for example I do it inside of Conversation class

//List adapter

```
class MessagesListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MessageViewHolder = MessageViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(viewType, parent, false))
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = Conversation.getCount()
    override fun reloadDataSet() {}
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(Conversation.getMessage(position))
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = when (Conversation.getMessage(position).response) {
        true -> R.layout.message_response
        false -> R.layout.message_sent
    }
}
```

//Message Holder

```
 class MessageViewHolder(private var item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {

    fun bind(message: TextMessage) {
        if (message.response) {
            item.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_response_bubble).text = message.text
        } else {
            item.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_user_bubble).text = message.text
        }
    }
}
```

//Activity class

```
  class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val listAdapter = MessagesListAdapter()
    private lateinit var messagesListView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)
        messagesListView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        messagesListView.adapter = listAdapter

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        //For messages to appear from bottom to top
        layoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
        messagesListView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    }

    //Code you call from activity to update the list
    private fun addMessage(message: TextMessage) {
        if (!message.isNullOrBlank()) {
            Conversation.add(message)
            listAdapter.notifyItemChanged(Conversation.getCount() - 1)
            messagesListView.smoothScrollToPosition(Conversation.getCount() - 1)

        }
    }
}

//Conversation class
public class Conversation {
    private static List<TextMessage> currentConversation;

    public static void clear() {
        currentConversation = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void add(final TextMessage message) {
        if (currentConversation == null) {
            clear();
        }
        currentConversation.add(message);
    }

    static TextMessage getMessage(final int pos) {
        if (currentConversation == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return currentConversation.get(pos);
    }

    static int getCount() {
        return currentConversation == null ? 0 : currentConversation.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `setStackFromEnd()` to the LinearLayoutManager solved it for me!

+1 for `smoothScrollToPosition()`. Saved me some time because I wanted to know how to do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with messages appearing in the wrong spot, or not appearing at all, the underlying problem is that your data set doesn't have the data your adapter thinks it should.

Imagine that you have a list of strings `["A", "B", "C"]`. You add two messages to it, but you only notify the adapter that you've added one. The adapter thinks the list is now `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`, but it is actually `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]`. This will eventually lead to problems.

In the code you've posted, you only have a single `notifyItemInserted()` call (for the bot's response to the user's message). But you've described a workflow that includes adding both a user message and a bot reply. That makes me think that you've missed a `notify` call you need.

You can replace all calls to `notifyItemInserted()` with `notifyDataSetChanged()` and see if this fixes the problem. In general, it is better to use `notifyItemInserted()`, but **if this fixes the problem** then you'll *know* that the problem is that you've missed a `notify` call you needed. Then you can go through the code very carefully and make sure that any time `mMessages` is changed you notify the adapter.

Comment: Adding to your answer, remember what a RecyclerView does... it re-uses. So "once the user scrolls" is a huge tip-off that the data isn't being updated when dequeued/re-used. Ben's answer specifically talks about "notify" for the adapter, but remember the view's cycle

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I actually have another notify call in an onClickListener for the user's text, and I tried to use notifyDataSetChanged(), to no avail. What I've noticed though is that only the bot messages are the ones that get mixed up, but  during debugging, everything seemed fine.

One problem I did have was that one message changed its value in the RecyclerView. It had the correct message displayed, then as the next message in the list was being bound, its text changed to that of the next message, and the last message in the list had the text of the first.

Comment: What is needed in addition to "notify?" I thought if the data was added to the list and it notified the adapter, the RecyclerView would be fine.

Comment: Nothing else is needed. As long as you notify the adapter of all structural changes, that's it. Perhaps the problem is different.

Comment: The other obvious place to look when the "wrong" data is being displayed is the method you're using to choose the current element from the "position" argument. If you're doing something more complicated than `list.get(position)` it's pretty easy to mess this up.